# How can I find more information about a Google cloud app that is listed as an "Authorized Application" in Gmail

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Specificially, I'm searching for why the Application "946277197574-f7mp4v1faacb1ndtpsliojjgcjbv16it.app.googleusercontent.com" shows up in details even though there are no Authorized Applications.

That string shows up as both the OAuth Domain Name and insidethe parentheses of  AuthorizedApplication(...).

I created a trial cloud log account and tried to use the console, but it is not clear to me whether that string is the AppId, or token or something else. I got no response. I didn't input any credentials.

If someone could provide an example of the html-post text, that would be great. (And I could look up the other weird ID).

Comment: Unless you have permission to the project number in the Client ID, you cannot obtain information. If you do have permission, you will find it in the Google Cloud Console under `APIs & Sevices` -> `Credentials`. Note: The first set of numbers is the Project Number. Edit your post with more details on context if I misunderstand the problem.